Remove very old commit that added a contributor to my repo
Almost 10 years ago I was playing with a bot (waffle.io to be precise) in my repo. It pushed a single commit adding a badge and I quickly stopped using the service and the badge.
It bothers me that waffle-iron is still being listed as a contributor to my repo. I know its a very non-important issue but it really bothers me.
How can I remove that specific commit so that this bot no longer appears as a contributor, disrupting my repo the bare minimum? Remember this is a 10 years old commit, I've made hundreds (thousands?) of commits since.
I understand there are multiple similar questions but they all sort of assume this is a somewhat recent commit and the solutions are all rather drastic.

To "remove a commit" you have to rewrite every subsequent one. This will also mean moving all of your tags. Your solutions are the same whatever the age (and whyever you want to drop a commit) and are drastic by necessity.

All solutions you have found should work regardless of whether the commit is 1 day or 10 years old.

@jonrsharpe that's what I feared. Guess it's not worth it

I am not sure if this will be helpful, but you can give it a try,
use git log to find the hash of that specific commit that you wish to remove. After that, use git rebase -i <hash-commit>, in the list find the commit you wish to delete and then remove its line from the list.
Now you can save and close the session.
Use git push --force to push the changes to remote repo.
Let me know if this worked.
Edit: Please note the risk of removing a commit, you do not want to damage your program and code in different branches.
